# Notify Activity from onClick of View object

Tags: android, android-intent

I seem to be stuck with a problem with an object communicating with my activity class. The object is a view object with an `onClick` method that when called I would like it to notify my activity class so that it can perform said action. Below is some example code of my situation (assume all conventional setup operations have already been made):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    //...other global methods and objects
    //Does not have access to instantiated Entry object(s)

    public void entryObjectWasClicked(){
        //perform said action
    } 
}

public class Entry extends View implements View.OnClickListener{
    //...other global methods and objects
    //Does not have access to the MainActivity object

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        //send a message to the MainActivity to 
        //somehow call the entryObjectWasClicked() method
    }
}
```

The only way (off the top of my head) that I could think about dealing with this problem is by creating a static method in `MainActivity` and then calling it from an anonymous `MainActivity` object in the `onClick` method of `Entry`. The problem with the static method approach is that any subsequent method/object/primitive usages in the static method force those methods/objects/primitives to be static. This defeats the purpose of then being able to have two different instances of the `MainActivity` object.

---

After some looking I came across using Broadcast messages, specifically using the `LocalBroadcastManager` to send an intent to the activity. [This code example](https://gist.github.com/Antarix/8131277) works for my model, but I want to know: is this the best way for me to go about sending messages to my `MainActivity` from my `Entry` object?

If there is a more effective way of doing all this, what would it be?

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things.  Don't override onClick for this.  Instead, have your activity call setOnClickHandler on your view, which sets a callback that's called when the view is clicked.  Then use the default implementation.

Comment: I understand that this would work, but with my project structure it is actually another class that is instantiating and dealing with the `Entry` objects.

Comment: Then it sounds like your architecture is screwey, and you should probably rethink it.  If you need a broadcast for simple UI effects, it means you've misarchitected your application.

Comment: I don't think I've misarchitectured my application, but for future use: where would you suggest I go to get a better understanding of the architecture that I should be following?

Answer (score -1):

Since you extend view, i guess you want to use it inside a layout. That means you may want to create a Listener for that. Example:

```
public class Entry extends View implements View.OnClickListener{
    private OnClickListener listener;
    public void setListener(OnClickListener listener) {
      this.listener = listener;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(){
       if (this.listener != null) this.listener.onClick(this);
    }
}
```

How you can inflate your layout in your Activity and access your custom view.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
     public void onCreate( ...) {
       Entry entry = findViewById(R.id.entry);
       entry.setListener(new OnClickListener(...));
     }
}
```

Comment: Except this is already built into Views.  just use setOnClickListener()

Comment: Yup, but it can be any listener, its just easy to explain in this case. Maybe he want to "  which is mostly used " extend the OnClickListeners behaviour. But you'r right. Its already "built in"

Comment: Setting the onClickListener is trivial to my question

Comment: Greg, if this is trivial then i think there's a problem in your design pattern. Creating a solution to notify somehow within a view is really a bad idea. Even if you share your data using eventbus/broadcastreceivers/observables/whatever. The best way to inform a view about view changes is using listeners

Comment: I'm not wanting to inform a view about a view change. I'm having the custom view invoke some code on the activity. Performing UI changes was just an example.

Comment: View (Activity) gets notified by the View (CustomView / Entry) -> updates code in its own view (Activity). 

View (CustomView) gets some push or notify -> updates code in the view (Activity) 

The behaviour is exactly the same except that a view (activity) can have multiple views while a view (custom view) cant have multiple views (activities). Could you provide a better use case? Maybe your informations are misleading

Comment: What I am asking about deals with what you first wrote in the above comment. "Activity gets notified by the Entry," this is the process I am asking about. What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: This is exactly the sample i wrote while the View (Entry) works like a proxy. The Entry itself has a Clicklistener. Only if the  activity hook itself as listener to the view, the click will get forwarded to the listener set by the activity. That means: Activity -> set Listener in the Entry. The Entry get changed somehow and the onclick get called. Now you can process the onclick and check if the activity got hooked into the entry. If yes (not null) you can forward it if you call onClick on the emitted listener. It sounds a little bit confusing but this is the way to go.

Comment: where do you intend to use the Entry object?

Comment: You say I should hook the activity to the view. How would I go about doing that?